# MVVM transfer between 2 different pages

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have `MainPaqe.cs` (`MainPaqe.xaml`) and `Periodic_Request.cs` (`Periodic_Request.xaml`), in addition, `Periodic_Request.xaml` has `TextBox` with name `TxtBlock_numRequest` and `Combobox` with name `CmbBox_lvlPriority` with possible 3 options.

The problem is how get user written numbers or strings from `TextBox` and `Combobox` in the `MainPaqe.cs`. I need to get all this information after pressing `button`.

I completely can`t understand how to write it and use that pattern, so this why I need actual code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try passing the data in a QueryString? Check out [this link](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-pass-data-between-pages-in-windows-phone-alternatives) for samples

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string uri = String.Format("/Periodic_Request.xaml?numRequest={0}", TxtBlock_numRequest.Text);
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @miguelarcilla, I wasted hours to solve this problem

Comment: @Rocketq No worries ;) GeekChamp is a really big help for a lot of those little questions. If you're doing MVVM, you could look at frameworks to make it easy on yourself. (http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/ is a good example)

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do if I have just a few of this things that need to be passed to the main page is define them as static properties in the App.xaml.cs file

Then you can do something like this;

```
MainPage_OnNavigatedTo(object sender, Eventargs args)
{
    if(App.YourProperty != null)
    {
         _viewmodel.RefreshValueForFoo(App.YourProperty);
    }
}
```

It's not the nicest solution but it gets the job done when you have just a few values that need to be passed around

Answer (score 1):

You could either send a querystring like miguel suggested, or have static properties, but both aren't too great. (why would I need to have a property everybody can see? or why would i have to create a querystring).

The solution when working with WPF usually lends itself in the use of the MVVM pattern, and in turn, using a messenger class to send a message. You can send whatever message you want, and whomever is supposed to listen to it, will receive it (once he register for that type of message).

I'm very happy with MVVM-Light implementation.

Here's a general example on how to use the messenger: http://jesseliberty.com/2011/01/06/windows-phone-from-scratch%E2%80%93mvvm-light-toolkit-soup-to-nuts-3/